# Using Task.Factory in Image class

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I am trying to make images load in different thread but image is never updated.

```
public class MyImage : System.Windows.Controls.Image
{
  public MyImage()
  {
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyImage_Loaded);
  }
  void MyImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    //mypath=@"c:\test.jpg";
    var t = Task<ImageSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetImage(mypath));
    Source = t.Result;
  }
```

[image: Error on Source]

Following works but it is the UI thread:

```
Source = GetImage(mypath);
```

I tried the same with BackgroundWorker but the result is the same.
Is it possible to do it like this without MVVM?

Comment: Why are you using a Task if you simply block the main thread by calling the Result property?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Is there an exception, nothing happens, what?  What is `mypath`?

Comment: @PeterRitchie mypath is path to image. There is no exception. If I try var t1 = Task<ImageSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetImage(mypath))
                    .ContinueWith(antecendent => { 
                        Source = antecendent.Result; 
                    }); I get "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: Images are bound to the thread they are created on. You need to load it in the UI thread.

Comment: @CoryNelson I know, but can I create ImageSource object on background thread and assign it to Images's source on the UI thread?

Comment: No, imagesource is STA threaded.

Comment: @MiloS when you get your `ImageSource` call `Freeze()` on it. This should allow you to use it on different thread

Comment: @dkozl Please copy this text as the answer so I can accept it. It is brilliant! It had to be something so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you create `ImageSource` on different thread then the one you want to use it on you get

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

exception and to solve your issue you should call [`Freeze()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your `ImageSource`. However even though you load image on different thread your code blocks UI thread until it's ready:

```
var t = Task<ImageSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetImage(mypath));
Source = t.Result; //this line blocks UI thread until Result is ready
```

If you want to avoid that change it to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   var source = GetImage(mypath);
   source.Freeze();
   this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Source = source);
});
```

This should load image on different thread and update `Source` when it's ready without blocking UI thread

Comment: Thank you very much! Freeze was the key (a word that does not come to mind these days). I also thought without Invoke it would wait until UI wants to update itself and it would update multiple images at the same time. Task Factory is great but it is easy to make small mistake and negate the benefit of running code in a different thread. It works great now!

Comment: It's easy to get this multithreading wrong. You can use your code if for example you would have something else of similar length to do between creating `Task` and waiting for `Result`

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a byte[] or a stream from your GetImage (or from its result), then use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to call a helper on the UI thread that reconstructs the image from the byte[]  or stream and updates MyImage's Source.

This is my working POC. You want to examine it for proper disposal of the stream and so on.
(Note: `disp` is the Dispatcher to "post" to the UI)

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var result = GetImage();
                    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    var stream = result;    
                    bitmap.BeginInit();
                    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;

                    bitmap.EndInit();
                    bitmap.Freeze();
                    stream.Dispose();
                    disp.Invoke(new Action(()=> MyImage.Source = bitmap));
                });
```

And the `GetImage()`:

```
    private MemoryStream GetImage()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(35000);
        var filePath = @"C:\temp\2013-01-08-235341.jpg";
        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            memoryStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
        }

        return memoryStream;
    }
```